# Export Keras Training History Plot inside Loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, keras

I'm training a Keras model in R inside a for-loop (yes I know, for-loops bad).  While plot(history) for the model works perfectly when I run the code one iteration at a time, it outputs a blank image when inside the loop.

Since this uses ggplot2, I've tried to set a delay via Sys.sleep(2) to see if there was some system lag associated with the plotting but it didn't help.

```
hist_nm_pre <- model %>% fit(
    x_fake, y_fake,
    batch_size = 500,
    epochs = transfer_epochs,
    validation_data = list(xy$x_val, xy$y_val),
    shuffle = TRUE
)

png(file=sprintf("output/iter_%d_pre.png", i), width=1200, height=800)
    plot(hist_nm_pre)
    Sys.sleep(2)
dev.off()
```

Is there a different way I should be exporting these plots?  Or is this a bug farther up the stack?

Comment: can't see where it's using `ggplot2`

Comment: The keras library uses ggplot2 to plot history if installed.   This code seems to work if I remove the ggplot2 library and use R-base to plot but that's not really a long term viable solution.